# How can I get the value from connection string?

Tags: c#

I have connection string:

```
<add name="fullDataBase"  
     connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Equipme;Integrated Security=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And then I can get name of catalog from it when I get this string using:

```
 string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[_connectionString].ConnectionString;
```

In my case it should be `Equipme`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx):

```
string initialCatalog = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString).InitialCatalog;
```

Comment: so in result I will have "Equipme" ?

Comment: @revolutionkpi - if the `connectionString` variable has the contents of the connection string you have posted, then yes, it will.

Answer (score 2):

This is your solution

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("fullDataBase").ToString()))
string initialCatalog=builder.InitialCatalog()
```

The `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` will create a ConnectionString or it will break the connection string into individual parts line Database name etc..

Comment: "Vote up and accept if it works"...please specify, its suggestion, request or command

Comment: The code is self explanatory to the asker, because it directly focus his needs.

Comment: still you need to answer my question, please specify, its suggestion, request or command